# How to debug Wake-on-lan not working sometimes?

Tags: linux, nixos, wake-on-lan

Could somebody point me to any strategies for debugging wake-on-lan?

I use nixOS, gnome, sometimes and put my desktop to suspend via the corner menu, sometimes it goes to suspend via inactivity.
Either way, 1-2 mins after it suspends, I send it a wake-on-lan magic packet from my phone. Sometimes it wakes up and sometimes it doesn’t.

I cant figure out the pattern of when it works and doesn’t. Any ideas?

Since it wakes up sometimes I'm assuming BIOS settings are ok

Comment: Maybe the packet was missed.  Try sending it multiple times, like 5-10x.  If that doesn't work, do it again 10-20 seconds later, and retry for 30 seconds.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be a Linux issue. Either your network or device is acting up. WoL doesn't depend on your target OS.

Comment: Im wondering if at different times it puts the pc in slightly different kinds of sleep/suspend. Can linux logs reveal how it transitions from sleep state to sleep state?

Comment: Also depends how the client sends the WOL: if not using a broadcast and using IP as payload, this requires to have the ARP entry still present on the system sending the unicast (the client, or the router).